# Processing 3, every int and float got replaced with "tweakmode_int[...]" respectively "tweakmode_float[...]" because of a bug

Tags: java, processing

I basically have thousands of lines of code.
While undoing a bunch of changes, Processing got buggy and messed up my code.
I am now left with thousands of nonfunctional lines of Java code, in which every integer and floating point number is replaced with a string "tweakmode_int[...]" or respectively "tweakmode_float[...]"
There over a thousand of non-variable numbers that got replaced.
Is there any way to recover it?

I am using Processing 3.3.5

Thank you

Comment: look into your repository. or your backup file. or recover your pc...

Answer (score 0):

The Processing editor has a find and replace tool. Just go to `Edit` and then `Find...` to show the dialog. There you can specify the text to search for, as well as the text to replace it with. This will allow you to quickly replace all `tweakmode_float` occurences with `float`, and the same thing for the `int` values.

As a side note, you should not be writing sketches that contain thousands of lines of code. At the very least, you need to split your code into multiple tabs. If your code is very complicated, you might even think about using [Processing as a Java library](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) and using a "real" IDE to write your code.

Comment: Thank you. I am using multiple tabs, but while the bug was occuring, I was switching between tabs. Of course, it had to corrupt the largest tab.
I am thinking about switching now.